# MySQL: Excluding some rows from the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table of consultant unavailabilities

```
c_id | start_date           |end_date
---------------------------------------------
937  | 2018-06-01 13:00:00  | 2018-06-01 20:00:00
937  | 2018-04-28 08:00:00  | 2018-04-28 18:00:00
938  | 2018-06-28 14:00:00  | 2018-06-28 16:00:00
938  | 2018-06-16 14:00:00  | 2018-06-16 17:00:00
939  | 2018-05-05 09:00:00  | 2018-05-05 12:00:00
939  | 2018-06-08 12:00:00  | 2018-06-08 16:00:00
```

Now I want to get the consultants available on June the 16th from 09:00 to 18:00
This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT c_id, start_date, end_date 
FROM consultant_unavailabilities 
WHERE start_date NOT BETWEEN '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00' 
AND end_date NOT BETWEEN '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00' 
GROUP BY c_id
```

which returns:

```
937  | 2018-06-01 13:00:00  | 2018-06-01 20:00:00
938  | 2018-06-28 14:00:00  | 2018-06-28 16:00:00
939  | 2018-05-05 09:00:00  | 2018-05-05 12:00:00
```

937 and 939 are ok, but 938 is not available.

The trick would be to ask MySQL not to get the ids which have a row of unavailabilitie on June the 16th from 09:00 to 18:00.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: 938 returns what the query should return? Are you sure thats incorrect

Comment: @nutic It's not related to boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery to find all the consultants who are busy during that period, then exclude them:

```
SELECT c_id, start_date, end_date
FROM consultant_availabilities
WHERE c_id NOT IN (
    SELECT c_id
    FROM consultant_unavailabilities 
    WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00' 
    OR end_date BETWEEN '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00')
```

Comment: Really? I think the test for overlaps is simpler

Comment: No, because there are multiple rows for each consultant. He wants to exclude a consultant completely if any of their rows overlap.

Comment: @Barmar +1  It's exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I think the `WHERE` condition in the subquery should be an `OR`, otherwise it will not return a consultant who is (e.g.) not available from 4pm to 7pm.

Comment: @Nick That's correct. When changing from NOT BETWEEN to BETWEEN, the AND changes to OR.

Comment: @Nick I don't want a consultant unavailable from 4pm to 7pm since in my example the consultant has to be available from 9am to 6pm.

Comment: @Duddy67 That's what I meant: the subquery (which returns the list of consultants who are NOT available) would not include a consultant who was unavailable from 4pm to 7pm until the AND was changed to an OR.

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I misunderstood your comment ;) Indeed, we need a OR not a AND to prevent to include a consultant who is unavailable from 4pm to 7pm.
Barmar's query seems to do the job properly. It just needs the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `GROUP BY` shouldn't be used without aggregation functions for the other columns that are being returned. Which `start_date` and `end_date` should it return in each group?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c_id, start_date, end_date 
FROM c_u 
WHERE (start_date < '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND end_date < '2018-06-16 09:00:00') 
OR
(start_date > '2018-06-16 18:00:00' AND end_date > '2018-06-16 18:00:00')
AND 
c_id NOT IN (SELECT c_id FROM c_u WHERE 
             (start_date BETWEEN '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00')
             OR
             (end_date BETWEEN '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00')
            )
            GROUP BY c_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a3716/7)

Comment: There's a lot of query here

Comment: Can we simplify it? I would love to see that.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(c_id INT NOT NULL
,start_date DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,end_date DATETIME NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(937,'2018-06-01 13:00:00','2018-06-01 20:00:00'),
(937,'2018-04-28 08:00:00','2018-04-28 18:00:00'),
(938,'2018-06-28 14:00:00','2018-06-28 16:00:00'),
(938,'2018-06-16 14:00:00','2018-06-16 17:00:00'),
(939,'2018-05-05 09:00:00','2018-05-05 12:00:00'),
(939,'2018-06-08 12:00:00','2018-06-08 16:00:00');


SELECT DISTINCT x.c_id 
           FROM my_table x
           LEFT
           JOIN
              ( SELECT c_id 
                  FROM my_table a  
                  WHERE '2018-06-16 09:00:00' <= a.end_date 
                    AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00' > a.start_date
              ) y
             ON y.c_id = x.c_id
          WHERE y.c_id IS NULL;
+------+
| c_id |
+------+
|  937 |
|  939 |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to filter IDs of consultants that you wish to keep:

```
SELECT c_id
FROM consultant_unavailabilities
GROUP BY c_id
HANING COUNT(*) = SUM(
    case when start_date BETWEEN '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00' 
        AND end_date between '2018-06-16 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-16 18:00:00'
        then 0 else 1 end
    )
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d598d6/2)

Above, `COUNT` gives you the total number of non-availability records for a consultant, while `SUM` gives the number of non-availability records excluding a specific time. When these two counts are equal, the consultant is available during your selected period.